# Json lazy loading images

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, lazy-loading

I have this Json file

```
http://localhost/mediamonks-15-years-gritt-glamour-website/deploy/htdocs/api/folder/Leuke%20Mensen/images
```

This is how i get the images from the API

```
$.ajax('http://localhost/mediamonks-15-years-gritt-glamour-website/deploy/htdocs/api/folder/Leuke%20Mensen/images').then(response =>
    {
        var temp = [];
        for(var i = 0; i<response.length; i++){
            temp.push('http://d1ftcqzt8gr3o4.cloudfront.net/'+response.data[i].thumb);
        }
        this.thumbnails(temp);

        var images = response.data.map((data:IImageData) =>
        {
            return {
                big: 'http://d1ftcqzt8gr3o4.cloudfront.net/'+ data.big,
                thumb: 'http://d1ftcqzt8gr3o4.cloudfront.net/'+ data.thumb
            }
        });
        this.images(images);
    });
```

So my question is: What is the best way to only get 10 images. Can i just do it with code or would be better of changing the api so that it wraps every 10 images into another object?

Comment: You can alter your api to receive an image index and an offset (representing the number of images you want to retrieve), for instance: `http://localhost/mediamonks-15-years-gritt-glamour-website/deploy/htdocs/api/folder/Leuke%20Mensen/images/5/150` will give you 150 images starting from the 5th image.

Comment: Why not use `$.getJSON()`?

Answer (score 0):

The most used solution for pagination is to use `startIndex` and `count`. You have to change your service and add startIndex and count get parameters. After that, you have to add at the end of the query (I suppose you use mysql) `limit` and pass `startIndex` and `count` variables.

The limit function works in that way: `limit 3, 7` means you want to get the rows from 4 to 10.